# Get Intervals Between Two Times

Tags: python, django, datetime

A User will specify a time `interval` of *n* secs/mins/hours and then two times (`start` / `stop`).

I need to be able to take this `interval`, and then step through the `start` and `stop` times, in order to get a list of these times. Then after this, I will perform a database look up via a `table.objects.filter`, in order to retrieve the data corresponding to each time.

I'm making some ridiculously long algorithms at the moment and I'm positive there could be an easier way to do this. That is, a more *pythonic* way. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you briefly explain your current approach?

Comment: Big monolithic bit of code that created a significant time for each *time + interval*, then looped the list and so on. It's pretty hideous.

Comment: @_bravado: Please post an outline or snippet of the code -- do not add comments to your own question.  Please update your question.  You own it, you can update it.  Please do not comment on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it fits nicely as a generator, too:

```
def timeseq(start,stop,interval):
    while start <= stop:
        yield start
        start += interval
```

used as:

```
for t in timeseq(start,stop,interval):
    table.objects.filter(t)
```

or:

```
data = [table.objects.filter(t) for t in timeseq(start,stop,interval)]
```

Comment: I really like your third suggestion! :)

Comment: Hmmm. When I do a simple: `list = []; data = [list.append(t) for t in timeseq(1258558882,1258558982,10)]` I am returned with `[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]` why is this?

Comment: `list.append(t)` evaluates to `None` (but has a side-effect on list - try printing that).

You can just write `data = list(timeseq(1258558882,1258558982,10))` if you want to evaluate the list.

Comment: New correct answer as this is exactly what I want! thanks a lot :)

Comment: Though, how do you print the 'side-effect on list'? :S Your last part worked perfectly though, but I'm just curious as to what you're referring to! thanks a lot :)

Comment: The code you posted starts with empty `list = []`.
Then it constructs another list with the comprehension `data = [...`.

The values for that comprehension are the return values from the calls to `list.append(t)`.

Now, `list.append(t)` returns `None`, but modifies `list` - ie, it has a side-effect rather than being a pure function that returns a result.
If you print `list` as well as `data`, you should see `list` has the results you wanted, although `data` is the sequence of `None` you posted before.

Did I explain that clearly? Hope this helps your comprehension ;D

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for something like this? (pseudo code)

```
t = start 
while t != stop: 
    t += interval 
    table.objects.filter(t)
```

Comment: That's so simple it's unreal. I really need to learn how to 'step back' from a problem.

Comment: i would use `t <= stop` because `(stop-start)%interval` may be different from 0

Answer (score 1):

What about ...

```
result = RelevantModel.objects.filter(relavant_field__in=[
    start + interval * i 
    for i in xrange((start - end).seconds / interval.seconds)
])
```

... ?

I can't imagine this is very different from what you're already doing, but perhaps it's more compact (particularly if you weren't using `foo__in=[bar]` or a list comprehension). Of course start and end would be datetime.datetime objects and interval would be a datetime.timedelta object.